# org.apache.commons.math3.transform FastFourierTransformer returns different value when input is Complex[] and Double[]

Tags: apache, math, fft

For this question, I'm using the Maths library from [Apache](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/transform/FastFourierTransformer.html)

My aim is to get my input back after performing an inverse fourier transform on the [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) results of the forward fourier transformation of the input values.

When I perform an inverse fourier transform on the [Complex value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number) results of the forward fourier transformation of the input, I get the correct output.

What am I possibly doing wrong?

```
public void fourierTestTemp(){
    double[] input = new double[]{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,66,888,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};//Length = 16

    double[] result = new double[input.length];//This double array will hold the results of the fourier transform
    FastFourierTransformer transformer = new FastFourierTransformer(DftNormalization.UNITARY);//The FastFourierTransformer class by Apache
    Complex[] complx = transformer.transform(result, TransformType.FORWARD);//Apply fourier transform to double[]

    //Go through Complex value results and obtain absolute value
    for (int i = 0; i < complx.length; i++) {
        result[i] = complx[i].abs();
    }

    //Perform inverse transform on the obtained absolute values from the forward transform.
    complx = transformer.transform(result, TransformType.INVERSE);

    //Go through Complex value results and obtain absolute value
    for (int i = 0; i < complx.length; i++) {
        result[i] = complx[i].abs();
    }

    //Print results
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(result[i]+",");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ifft(abs(fft(x))) is only the identity if x is strictly symmetric (can be constructed out of only cosine basis vectors of the DFT).  Your test vector is not.

Cosines are symmetric functions.  Sines are anti-symmetric.

If x is not symmetric, fft(x) will not be real, thus the abs() function will rotate some of the phase results, thus distorting the ifft output waveform.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How do you think I can convert a vector such as [1,2,3] into the form you're talking about?

Comment: [1,2,3,2] is circularly symmetric around 1.